# Java - A method to format Strings that adds \r characters without being asked to

Tags: java, string, format

I am trying to create a method that takes as input a `String` matrix and returns a `String` In which all the cells of a column are horizontally aligned, no matter the length of the `String` in the cell.
To make an example, if the input is:

```
        String[][] test = new String[][] {
            new String[] { "0",     "01",   "0002"},
            new String[] { "0003",  "4",    "5"},
        };
```

Then the output must be `"0\t\t01\t0002\n0003\t4\t5\n"`, i.e.:

```
0       01  0002
0003    4   5
```

Now, my code doesn't do exactly what I want (a problem with defining the number of tabulation to add as padding) but that is not my main problem. My main problem is that for *some* reasons there are carriage returns (`\r`) spontaneously added to my output `String`.

In the above example, the output wouldn't be `"0\t\t01\t0002\n0003\t4\t5\n"` but `"0\t\t01\t0002\r\n0003\t4\t5\r\n"`.

I know, visually it is the same. But I need the output of this method to do something else and I suspect the carriage returns are giving problems. Anyone has an idea on why those `\r` grow like mushrooms on my `String`s?

---

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {
    /** The maximum length of the character {@code \t}. */
    public static int spaceLengthOfTab = 8;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String converted = CanBePrinted.formatAndConvertToString(null, table, obj -> obj.toString() );
        
        String[][] test = new String[][] {
            new String[] { "0",     "01",   "0002"},
            new String[] { "0003",  "4",    "5"},
        };
        System.out.println(formatAndConvertToString(null, test, new StringBuffer()).toString());
        
        String output = "0      01  0002\r\n" + 
                "0003   4   5\r\n" + 
                "";
        
    }
    /** Adds to the input {@link StringBuffer} a {@link String} representing the {@code table} 
     * formatted in such a way to ensure all cells in a row are separated with an appropriate number 
     * of {@code \t} and all rows with {@code \n}.
     * @param header A row that must appear above the table. Can be {@code null}, in which case the parameter will be ignored.  */
    public static StringBuffer formatAndConvertToString(String[] header, String[][] table, StringBuffer support) {
        int[] columnMaximumWidth = new int[table[0].length];
        int row, column;
        
        // Find spaces
        if( header != null )
        for(column=0 ; column<table[0].length ; column++)
            columnMaximumWidth[column] = header[column].length();
        
        for(column=0 ; column<table[0].length ; column++)
            for(row=0 ; row<table.length ; row++)
                columnMaximumWidth[column] = 
                    columnMaximumWidth[column] < table[row][column].length()
                        ? table[row][column].length()
                        : columnMaximumWidth[column];
            
        // Create string
        if( header != null )
            {
            for(column=0 ; column<table[0].length ; column++)
                support.append(header[column])
                .append( column == table[0].length - 1 ? "" :   // The last cell must not be padded
                        Strings.repeatChar('\t', 1+tabs(columnMaximumWidth[column], header[column].length()) ));
            support.append('\n');
            }
        for(row=0 ; row<table.length ; row++)
            {
            for(column=0 ; column<table[0].length ; column++)
                support.append(table[row][column]).append( column == table[0].length - 1 ? "" : // The last cell must not be padded
                        Strings.repeatChar('\t', tabs(columnMaximumWidth[column], table[row][column].length())+1));
            support.append('\n');
            }
        return support;
    }
    /** Returns the number of {@code \t} needed to append at the cell to ensure it has the same length of the rest of the column.   */
    public static int tabs(int columnWidth, int cellWidth) {
        if( columnWidth == cellWidth )      return 0;
        if( columnWidth-1 == cellWidth )    return 0;
        return (int) (Math.ceil( (columnWidth-cellWidth)/ ((double)spaceLengthOfTab) ))
                - ( cellWidth % spaceLengthOfTab == 0 ? 1 : 0 );
    }
    /** Returns a {@code String} composed of a character {@code c} repeated {@code numberOfRepetitions} times.
     * 
     * @param c
     * @param numberOfRepetitions
     * @return
     */
    public static String repeatChar(char c, int numberOfRepetitions){
        StringBuilder outputProducer = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0 ; i<numberOfRepetitions ; i++)
            outputProducer.append( String.valueOf(c) );
        return outputProducer.toString();
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Just FYI Java uses newline ("\n") instead of carriage return in most situations.   For printing to the screen I would do that.

Comment: `Anyone has an idea on why those \r grow like mushrooms` If you're not adding them manually then something in the system is.  Certain high level print routines will use the local system EOL sequence, which on Windows I think is "\r\n".  READ THE DOCS on all methods you are calling, any that talk about using a local or system EOL might be the culprit.

Comment: [`System.lineSeparator()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) covers this.

Comment: Nothing in the code you pasted (other than `String output = `, which I think you added as a sort-of comment to explain what your output is) contains or would add an `\r`. Therefore this code cannot possibly do what you say it is doing. You are running different code, or there is more code that you didn't paste, that is doing this.

Comment: BTW I tested that code - removing the `Strings.` and assigning the result of the method to a variable so I could search for `\r` - none found. How exactly you know there are some?

Comment: @user16320675 I copy-pasted the output from the Eclipse console. (and it is not a feature of the console itself: in the tests I did with the original input, I forced the program to make an exception just after computing the output String so I could use the Eclipse debug tool and check the exact value of the output. Every \n had a \r before.